# Rotating a canvas is only working the first time

Tags: jquery, canvas, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a canvas on every mouseover, but it's only working the first time.
You can play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/h3Z7j/2/

The reason I'm rotating it 0 degrees is to convert it to canvases on load, since I'm loading `img`'s the first time.

rotation script: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/downloads/detail?name=jquery.rotate.1-1.js

```
<div class="gameboard">
    <img width="40" height="40" id="1-1" src="http://www.netbsd.org/images/download-icon-orange.png" alt="">
    <img width="40" height="40" id="2-1" src="http://www.netbsd.org/images/download-icon-orange.png" alt="">
    <img width="40" height="40" id="1-2" src="http://www.netbsd.org/images/download-icon-orange.png" alt="">
    <img width="40" height="40" id="2-2" src="http://www.netbsd.org/images/download-icon-orange.png" alt="">
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".gameboard img").each(function () {
        $(this).rotateLeft(0);
    });
    $(".gameboard canvas").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).rotateLeft();
    });
});
```

**edit**
If there are other rotation scripts that work better I'll happily change to that.

Comment: I'm not aware of what the rotateLeft() method is doing to your img, but maybe there is another naming after this method is executed.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to apply something to the rotated canvas after it has been rotated? I'm not sure how though. `mouseover`->`rotateLeft`->`add new mouse over`

Comment: Did you look up the documentation of this libary so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Rory's answer you can achieve one spin per mouseover by setting a flag to true/false on mouseover/mouseout:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stopSpin = false;
    $(".gameboard img").each(function () {
        $(this).rotateLeft(0);
    });
    $(".gameboard").delegate('canvas', 'mouseover', function () {
        if (!stopSpin){
            $(this).rotateLeft();
        }
        stopSpin = true;
    });
    $(".gameboard").delegate('canvas', 'mouseout', function () {
        stopSpin = false;
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/CK5hh/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the `canvas` element is being removed, and then readded to the DOM. This is then losing the `mouseover` handler placed on it. If you attach your event with `delegate` instead, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".gameboard img").each(function () {
        $(this).rotateLeft(0);
    });
    $(".gameboard").delegate('canvas', 'mouseover', function () {
        $(this).rotateLeft();
    });
});
```

Although I'm not sure the effect is exactly what you're after :)

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h3Z7j/5/)

Comment: Looks like this will spin the canvas as long as the mouse is over. I'd like it to just turn once on mouseover and then stop.

Comment: The problem is because the plugin is removing/adding the element to the DOM. Even though the mouse isn't moving, because a new element is created underneath it, the event is fired. This means the element will constantly spin. I don't believe there is a fix for this without amending the source of the plugin which creates the `canvas` elements.